# Exclamation mark doesn't work in trigger() when using event namespace in jQuery 1.9

Tags: jquery

Here is the code:

```
$("div").on("click",function(){
       console.log("click");
});
$("div").on("click.plugin", function(){
       console.log("click.plugin");
});
$("button").click(function() {
      $("div").trigger("click!");    
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div>test.</div>
<button >Trigger event according to namespace</button>
```

When I [run the code under jQuery 1.8.3](http://jsfiddle.net/un9aP/), it works. When I click button, it logs `click` in the console.

But when I [change to jQuery 1.9.1](http://jsfiddle.net/un9aP/1/), nothing happens when I press the button. It seems like the exclamation mark doesn't work anymore in 1.9.1.

I can't find this change in the 1.9 upgrade guide. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Never seen that before. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @juhana never seen that either. Docs say it should trigger only not-namespaced handlers.

Comment: @bažmegakapa Where did you read in Docs? Can you point that out to me?

Comment: I can find only non-official mentions. Undocumented feature?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger

Comment: possible duplicate of [trigger event with jquery without a namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691402/trigger-event-with-jquery-without-a-namespace)

Comment: @bažmegakapa - please note: as stated on the docs.jquery.com front page: *The references on docs.jquery.com are obsolete. Please see http://api.jquery.com for up-to-date documentation.*

Comment: @Spudley You're right, Google fooled me...

Answer (score 5):

Use `.$` instead of `!`

```
$("button").click(function() {
      $("div").trigger("click.$");    
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B2yVj/)** *<sub>[Credits: Tim B James]</sub>*

Comment: @bažmegakapa, The funny thing about that page was that it was linked to another SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691402/trigger-event-with-jquery-without-a-namespace). Ha ha. But seen the demo and it works.

Comment: @TimBJames, Thanks I will add that to the answer.

Comment: @bažmegakapa, Seems like a undocumented hack. Cannot find it anywhere and am too lazy to dig the source :(

Comment: jQuery is not using regex to find the event name. This only happens to work by accident.

Comment: @Tomalak, Thank you for the explanation. I better remove that from the answer then :)

Comment: The reason why appending `'.$'` works is because of the `if ( type.indexOf(".") >= 0 )` part (see my answer). Since there is no event namespace `'$'` it seems as if only `click` was triggered.

Answer (score 4):

This is how [jQuery 1.8.3](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js) looks like:

```
trigger: function( event, data, elem, onlyHandlers ) {

    // Don't do events on text and comment nodes
    if ( elem && (elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 8) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Event object or event type
    var cache, exclusive, i, cur, old, ontype, special, handle, eventPath, bubbleType,
        type = event.type || event,
        namespaces = [];

    // focus/blur morphs to focusin/out; ensure we're not firing them right now
    if ( rfocusMorph.test( type + jQuery.event.triggered ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( type.indexOf( "!" ) >= 0 ) {
        // Exclusive events trigger only for the exact event (no namespaces)
        type = type.slice(0, -1);
        exclusive = true;
    }

    if ( type.indexOf( "." ) >= 0 ) {
        // Namespaced trigger; create a regexp to match event type in handle()
        namespaces = type.split(".");
        type = namespaces.shift();
        namespaces.sort();
    }

    // ...
```

Notice the *"Exclusive events trigger only for the exact event"* section.

And this is [jQuery 1.9.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js):

```
trigger: function( event, data, elem, onlyHandlers ) {
    var handle, ontype, cur,
        bubbleType, special, tmp, i,
        eventPath = [ elem || document ],
        type = core_hasOwn.call( event, "type" ) ? event.type : event,
        namespaces = core_hasOwn.call( event, "namespace" ) ? event.namespace.split(".") : [];

    cur = tmp = elem = elem || document;

    // Don't do events on text and comment nodes
    if ( elem.nodeType === 3 || elem.nodeType === 8 ) {
        return;
    }

    // focus/blur morphs to focusin/out; ensure we're not firing them right now
    if ( rfocusMorph.test( type + jQuery.event.triggered ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( type.indexOf(".") >= 0 ) {
        // Namespaced trigger; create a regexp to match event type in handle()
        namespaces = type.split(".");
        type = namespaces.shift();
        namespaces.sort();
    }

    // ...
```

Here the entire section is missing (it's also not in the omitted bit).

It seems as if jQuery has dropped support for this feature. The variable `exclusive` has been removed from the whole source.

Looking at the source of version 1.9.1 I don't see a way for you to get the desired functionality without resorting to hacks.

Comment: Thanks for all you guys's answers, and do we have jQuery engineers in this website, maybe we can tell them to put this change in jQuery 1.9.1 upgrade guide.

Comment: jQuery has [a bug tracking system](http://bugs.jquery.com/). Open a ticket and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, Tomalak, I've already post the issue on tracking system and got the resonse, they will add it in upgrade guide. Here is the link:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13873

Comment: On this [line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L244) jQuery seems to be using regex to match the event names isn't it?

Comment: It seems like it, but there is no documentaion for it.

Comment: @user2301368, The hack I posted should be enough to solve your problem until they add it on their next upgrade. Good Luck :)